# PhpStorm terminal strange characters

Tags: phpstorm

My terminal sometimes changes all characters like in the following image

[image]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No solution yet, unfortunately.
Please vote and follow here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-180204